# What does "promotional consideration" at the end credits mean?

Tags: credits, product-placement, brooklyn-nine-nine

At the end of every (or most) Brooklyn Nine-Nine episodes there is a "Promotional consideration furnished by Apple" message shown during the credits.

Does that mean that Apple pays for the product placement in the series? Or do they supply the products used as props (mobile phones, laptops, etc)? Is there a difference in the way to disclaim that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means Apple provided products.

> It means Apple has provided products either for use in the program, or as a prize.
>
> For instance, if you were on Let’s Make A Deal and you won a brand new iPad Pro, the company that produces Let’s Make A Deal does not buy the iPad Pro. Instead, Apple provides the unit for free in exchange for the publicity it generates. The free iPad is furnished to promote Apple products, therefore the item is considered promotional.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[What does promotional consideration furnished by Apple mean? - Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-does-promotional-consideration-furnished-by-Apple-mean)</sub>

So, yes it is something of a advertising method.